# Why am I getting NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, input, nosuchelementexception

Here is my code:

```
while (menuExit == true) {
        System.out.println (SEPARATE_LINE);
        System.out.println ("Which do you want to do ? ");
        System.out.println (SEPARATE_LINE);
        System.out.println ("1.Register");
        System.out.println ("2.Sign in");
        System.out.println ("3.Check shop status");
        System.out.println ("0.Exit");
        System.out.println (SEPARATE_LINE);
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice as number:");
        do{
        try{
        int selectMain = input.nextInt();
        if(selectMain == 1){
            register(currentNum , customers);
            customers.clear();
            customers = ReadData.readCustomerData();
         }else if(selectMain == 2){
            signIn(customers,historys,cusData,hisData);
        }else if(selectMain == 3){
            CheckData.checkShopStatus(shops,shopData);
            
        }else if(selectMain == 0){
            System.out.println ("Thank you");
            menuExit = false;
        }else {
            System.out.println ("Your input are wrong , Please enter again.");
        }
        continueInput = false;
        }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
            System.out.println("Please enter again.");
            input.nextLine();
        }
        
    }while (continueInput);
    input.close();
```

This is the menu of my program , when I enter into one of these selection and come back to the menu , I got NoSuchElementException , the error point to the line int selectMain = input.nextInt();. Please someone help me , thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You have continueInput = false in the try block in such a way that it means that it will run regardless of the user input. This means the dowhile loop exits on the next try, and the input is closed. however, because this is in another while loop, it tries to get another input, even though the input scanner is closed! This gets you the NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Instead of placing input.close() in the outer while loop, put it outside of the outer while loop. This would mean that the scanner would only close after all the inputs have been performed.

Comment: I delete in input.close() but it still get the same error.

Comment: @WeiJunTee just tried it with my own code and it worked. Do you have any input.close() in your other methods? If so get rid of them. Also, i didn't say to delete input.close(), but to only move it out of the outer while loop. Also, on further exception, set the boolean continueInput to true every time the outer while loop restarts, i.e. do continueInput = true before your dowhile block.